# Isotope container not center aligning

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I'm using Isotope for my portfolio site and I'm running into some trouble trying to center the grid items. Here's my folio for reference:

http://vontheodore.com

The below jsfiddle is using the same dimensions and margins, and seems to be working perfectly. As far as I can tell, my container is what's causing the problem; it's not centered the same way that the container in the jsfiddle is. Mine appears to stretch the entire width of the page no matter what I do. The only things I've modified are the sortBy and itemSelector properties where I'm initializing the Isotope grid:

http://jsfiddle.net/P6JGY/2045/

```
$container.isotope({
    // disable window resizing
    resizable: false,
    itemSelector: '.post',
    sortBy : 'random',
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: colW
}
```

I've already checked other answers and tried Perfect Masonry to no avail!

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use isotope v2 and 'isFitWidth: true' and also, an updated jQuery ( you had 1.5 in your jsfiddle).

Here is an updated jsfiddle [isotope v2 centered](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/ssdo7rht/)

```
$(function(){

var $container = $('#container'),
  $body = $('body'),
  colW = 360,
  columns = null;

 $container.isotope({
 // disable window resizing
  resizable: false,
 masonry: {
  columnWidth: colW,
    isFitWidth: true
}
});

$(window).smartresize(function(){
// check if columns has changed
var currentColumns = Math.floor( ( $body.width() -10 ) / colW );
if ( currentColumns !== columns ) {
  // set new column count
  columns = currentColumns;
  // apply width to container manually, then trigger relayout
  $container.width( columns * colW )
    .isotope('reLayout');
}

}).smartresize(); // trigger resize to set container width

});
```